# Java app blocking when launched from another

Tags: java

I have two applications, both written in Java. The first is a simple loader/monitor - it checks for updates for the second application on a remote site, downloads them if available, then launches the second application using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -jar MyApp.jar", null, new File("C:\MyWorkingDir"))`. The first app then sits there, periodically checking the second is running (using Sigar) and relaunching it if it stops. It continues to check for updates every hour, and if these are present, kills the second application, updates the files and restarts it.

The second application sends and receives SNMP messages to/from a manager after monitoring various aspects of the system, again using Sigar. It also periodically checks for updates to the first application on a remote server and downloads and updates when these are available.

If I launch the second application on its own (using `javaw -jar MyApp.jar`), the application works fine.

If I launch the first application (using `javaw -jar MyLauncher.jar`), one of two things happens. On my development machine, it works fine; on all other servers I've tested against, the second gets so far, then waits for a period of time between 20 mins to 2 hours before continuing. If I kill the first application, the second will then continue on as normal immediately.

There is no particular piece of code that causes it to stall - the log indicates that it happens in different places on different runs and different machines. Sometimes, it can occur between two consecutive calls to log4j. For example, one place it has stalled is:

```
    public static void Start(AgentConfig config) {

        LogHelper.Log("Starting SNMP Listener on udp:127.0.0.1/" + config.get_listenerServerPort());

        try {

            LogHelper.Log("Creating address");

            UdpAddress udpAddress = new UdpAddress("127.0.0.1/" + config.get_listenerServerPort());

            <snipped for brevity>
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogHelper.Error(e);
        }
```

When it goes into "wait mode", we see the following in the log:

```
    500  [main] INFO  root  - Starting SNMP Listener on udp:127.0.0.1/163
    7199578 [main] INFO  root  - Creating address
```

So, it appears to be having issues entering the try block - but after (7199578-500)ms = 7199s = almost exactly 2 hours, it gets over these and is able to continue on anyway.

The code for these projects is partitioned into four projects - common routines used by the other three (including the logging helper); the file updater (used by the other two); and the main code for each of the two primary applications. I've tried both adding the required projects to the projects section of the build path in Eclipse, and building a jar for each. There is no difference in either case. Each project uses log4j, the file updater uses commons-net-3-3, both main apps use Sigar and the primary SNMP application uses snmp4j.

I've got the JDK SE 7u25 on my development machine (Win7 Pro 64-bit), JRE SE 7u25 on the server (Win2003 Server R2 32-bit).

Java isn't my primary development environment, and I haven't been able to find any pointers elsewhere due to the fairly nebulous problem definition.

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO it is more related with OS setting for connection timeout.

Comment: The second application hangs before any connections are initiated every time. Depending on the spec of the machine, it can happen before it has entered any methods that attempt to open connections.

Comment: Have you tried a "ping 127.0.0.1" on your ops machine? This sounds like a network connection and timeout issue, probably something in the configuration of the host.

Comment: That works fine. I agree it sounds like a network/timeout issue, but running on its own, the 2nd app does not stall but runs as I would expect. Both apps check and FTP server on startup, but this is successful in both cases. I even rewrote the FTP client to see if this was related, but the problem still exists with the revised code.

Comment: Is it possible that host is already bound to an existing listener on the server (netstat -a)? Or is the port you're requesting a restricted (< 1024) port and you're running as admin on your box but not as admin on the ops box?